# How to resize image in pure code using Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following method `var res = await _createChartImage();` which returns an image un byte data that I later I send to firebase `await widget.firebaseRepository.saveChart(wiijiiChart, res);`

I would like to resize the image using dart and not the Flutter image package I would then need to convert it back to byte data

Comment: So I don't want to use the image package at all its very slow and I had some encoding issues

Comment: I'm looking for a pure dart way

Answer (score 0):

try this for resizing image, [bitmap](https://pub.dev/packages/bitmap):

You can create from a headed Uint8List:

```
import 'package:bitmap/bitmap.dart';

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.fromHeadful(imageWidth, imageHeight, theListOfInts); // Not async
```

Or a headless:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.fromHeadless(imageWidth, imageHeight, theListOfInts); // Not async
```

This is useful when you are dealing with the Uint8List that ByteData generates.

```
import 'package:bitmap/bitmap.dart';

Bitmap bitmap = await Bitmap.fromProvider(NetworkImage("http://pudim.com.br/pudim.jpg"));
Bitmap resizedBitmap = bitmap.apply(BitmapResize.to(width: 50, height: 50));;
Uint8List headedBitmap = resizedBitmap.buildHeaded();
```

Comment: Don't think that would work my image is already in byte data

Comment: updated, you can also create bitmap with Uint8List